# how to get an empty for an object to move with the object?

Tags: animation

I have done a couple of tutorials to do with simple car models animated in the rigid world. What I have noticed is that empties associated with the moving objects, like wheels and the car body stay where they are while the objects move off. You then see a long dashed line stretching from the empty to wherever the object is.

Shouldn't empties for moving objects move with their objects? Is there a way to make those kind of empties travel with their objects? I have just thought of turning off the visibility of empties, which makes things look better but can anyone comment on my query. In rendering they would disappear anyway I know.

Comment: The logic is the other way around:  if the object is parented to an empty, you move the empty and the object follows, or you parent all of the objects and emptys to another empty (or bone, or any object you want) and move that, so that the whole hierarchy follows.

Answer (score 0):

Select all the objects and the empties you want to move together and click Ctrl+J. You Group the objects and they move together.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're talking about parenting the wheels to empties and then parenting the empties to the main body? To parent, select the child, then the parent, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (to unparent, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>).